# Python Matplotlib bar chart with categories

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have data (duration of a certain activity) for two categories (Monday, Tuesday). I would like to generate a bar chart (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3eoA.png)). Bars above a threshold (different for both categories) should have a different color; e.g. on Mondays data above 10 hours should be blue and on Tuesdays above 12 hours. Any ideas how I could implement this in seaborn or matplotlib?

Thank you very much.

```
Monday = [5,6,8,12,5,20,4, 8]
Tuesday=[3,5,8,12,4,17]
```

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3eoA.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw two barplots, using an array of booleans for the coloring (`hue`):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

monday = np.array([5, 6, 8, 12, 5, 20, 4, 8])
tuesday = np.array([3, 5, 8, 12, 4, 17])

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4), sharey=True)
palette = {False: 'skyblue', True: 'tomato'}
sns.barplot(x=np.arange(len(monday)), y=monday, hue=monday >= 10, palette=palette, dodge=False, ax=ax0)
ax0.set_xlabel('Monday', size=20)
ax0.set_xticks([])
ax0.legend_.remove()
sns.barplot(x=np.arange(len(tuesday)), y=tuesday, hue=tuesday >= 12, palette=palette, dodge=False, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('Tuesday', size=20)
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.legend_.remove()
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with booleans for hue]